# Python: split a string delimited by given object type

Tags: python, string, split

How can I split a string, where the delimiter is a Python data type?

For example:

```
str_to_split = 'a1b2c'
str_to_split.split(int)
# ['a','b','c']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [re.split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split):

```
>>> import re
>>> thingToSplit = 'a1b2c'
>>> re.split('\d+', thingToSplit)
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Or, apply [isdigit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) check:

```
>>> [item for item in thingToSplit if not item.isdigit()]
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), like this

```
from itertools import groupby
print ["".join(g) for k,g in groupby('a1b2c', key=str.isdigit) if not k]
# ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: You should be able to do `groupby('a1b2c', key=str.isdigit)` instead of the lambda.

Comment: @iCodez Thanks man :) I updated the answer with your suggestion.